# Logging to a log table in a function shows the same time for all actions in it although they are minutes apart

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have function that writes to a log table with a `timestamp` field with `default current_timestamp`. My problem is that all logs from a function run always get the same timestamp, even though in reality the logs at the start of run and the end of run and they are at least few minutes apart.

I don't know if it matters but writing to the log table is done via another function `write_to_log`.

How can I make the log writes show the real time and not (I guess) the time of transaction?

Answer (score 4):

You will need one of `statement_timestamp()` or `clock_timestamp()` functions, which are indeed a PostgreSQL extension.  These can and do change during a transaction.

See also Jonathan' answer and the docs:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT

Answer (score 3):

The SQL standard requires the database server to maintain the fiction that an SQL statement executes instantaneously.  Therefore, while a statement is running, time is frozen.  Typically, you'll find there's a non-standard function that does provide the (real, non-frozen) current time, but the core functions defined by the standard (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIME) are not allowed to change while the statement is executing.